# How to hide one DIV and show one DIV in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have code below :

```
<div class="P1">
Testing OK
<input type="button" value="OK1" id="bp1">
</div>

<div class="P2">
Testing OK
<input type="button" value="OK2" id="bp2">
</div>
```

And jQuery code below :

```
$("#bp1").click(function(){
        $(".P1").hide();
        $(".P2").show();
    });
```

But when it's not working.

Why ? And how to fix ?

Thanks you so much.

**UPDATE**
It's working when I remove `$(".P1").hide();` **OR** `$(".P2").show();` from my code

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library? The code looks like it should work fine.

Comment: Yea you probably don't have jQuery included, the JSFiddle for this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/frakukm0/

Comment: its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/znyfpev4/ . somthing is missing on your. it should be jquery library

Comment: It's working when I remove $(".P1").hide(); or $(".P2").show(); from my code. Why ?

Comment: I literally copied the code, posted in a snippet, included jquery and worked fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#bp1").click(function(){
        $(".P1").css("display","none");
        $(".P2").css("display","block");
    });
```

You can hide and show in this way

Comment: There is no need to change the `display` property, OP's code should work as is.

Comment: Please, you can tell me why my code is not working ? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, try including this in your html page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Once you include that, your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have click handlers for each of the buttons

```js
$("#bp1").click(function(){
        $(".P1").hide();
        $(".P2").show();
    });

$("#bp2").click(function(){
        $(".P2").hide();
        $(".P1").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="P1">
Testing OK P1
<input type="button" value="OK1" id="bp1">
</div>

<div class="P2">
Testing OK P2
<input type="button" value="OK2" id="bp2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$("#bp1").click(function(){
    $(".P1").removeClassName('hidden');
    $(".P2").addClassName('hidden');
});
```

The property `hidden` should be added to the css.

```
hidden {
visibility: hidden;
}
```